# GPS is not working when the application is running as root user

Tags: android, location, root

I am working on app that is related to security. Application can not be removed even though user reset the device to factory settings. To do this device must be rooted. However, when I tried to obtain the location as `root` user I am getting this error on `Android Jellybean (4.1.1)` up

```
uncaughtException # Exception found!!
java.lang.SecurityException: invalid UID 0
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:659)
at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:664)
at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:486)
```

When i looked into the Android source code, I saw Google has added extra security in `LocationManagerService.java` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/com/android/server/LocationManagerService.java)

In `requestLocationUpdates` function it calls

```
 checkPackageName(Binder.getCallingUid(), packageName);
```

This is the `checkPackageName` function

```
 private void checkPackageName(int uid, String packageName) {
    if (packageName == null) {
        throw new SecurityException("packageName cannot be null");
    }
    String[] packages = mPackageManager.getPackagesForUid(uid);
    if (packages == null) {
        throw new SecurityException("invalid UID " + uid);
    }
    for (String pkg : packages) {
        if (packageName.equals(pkg)) return;
    }
    throw new SecurityException("invalid package name");
```

}

Any ideas how to get this fixed ? Please advice if you had similar problems how to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before calling to location service:

```
final long ident = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
```

After calling:

```
Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(ident);
```